# How to do formmating with combination of pandas dataframe.to_excel and xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to write nice-formatted excel files with dataframe.to_excel-xlsxwriter combo?
I am aware that it is possible to format cells when writing with pure xlsxwriter. But dataframe.to_excel takes so much less space.
I would like to adjust cell width and add some colors to column names.

What other alternatives would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

I found xlwings. It's intuitive and does all the things I want to do. Also, it does well with all pandas data types.